# Display subgrid in dynamics crm portal

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-portals

I have a Dynamics 365 portal page that displays a form on the Incident entity. In that form I have a subgrid from a different entity. Problem: when I open the form in portals I see the whole form, except for the subgrid. Its just blank (see image). [image]

I have tried following these two guides https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/configure-web-form-subgrid & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/assign-entity-permissions. thinking it was a security issue. But it does not appear to make any difference.

If anyone has any idea what I am overlooking/missing I would very much appreciate it.

Thank you.
Edit 1: Possibly the subgrid is not being displayed due to no data. I will investigate this.

Comment: If your subgrid will be rendered correctly but there ware no data you will still be able to see the subgrida with message "No records found". If you see this form inside CRM can you se the subgrid in there? IF yes, you can make sure that the entity permission for the records of this other entity is there and your user has access on it. On the Enitty Form metadata you can also configure further the subgrid ...

Comment: Hi @B.Irena. There were data present. That was not the issue, as you also state. We ended up coding the whole thing in HTML due to other constraints. We did actually find a fix for this specific thing. But I honestly cannot remember what it was.

Answer (score 0):

If the form was in insert mode, sub-grids will not appear. The record needs to be in edit mode for sub-grids to show up on portal.